# UITabelView, detail view empty first time I mark a row

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have an diary app, based on UITableView and CoreData, all works just fine but there is one little tim thing that is strange.
When I recompile the app and mark a row to see the details, the detail view is empty, if I go back and click the again it is populated as it should be.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the data for the UITableView's datasource, you should call [`-reload`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple%5Fref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData).

```
[myTableView reload];
```

Comment: I see that I have provided to little info and therefore it is hard to answer on my qustion. I will add a new question with loadas more info and code.

Comment: @swe_mattias I have the same problem, did you find a soln for it. Eventhough it quite an old post, but if remember it.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @" ";
```